# Taking PTO for giving interviews

Tags: job-search

I have been taking PTO to give interviews. I have been giving family reasons but my manager is getting suspicious. Is it possible for my manager to deny any further PTO in California? In which case can I say that I am sick and produce a doctor's certificate?

Comment: To summarize - it appears that you're asking if it's OK to lie in order to go about doing what you want. My answer to that is, no, that's not allowed. And if you get fired after your employer discovers you've lied I doubt a court will give you a sympathetic ear. I suggest that you take vacation to cover your interviews.

Comment: The answer to this either falls in company specific regulations or in labor law, both of which are out of scope for this SE.

Comment: Bob Jarvis, PTO is vacation time.

Comment: Basically, I don't have to give a reason to take PTO. I tell my manager informally I have family problems. PTO is sick as well as vacation time. I was just wondering if my manager can deny PTO as per California law.

Answer (score 3):

Paid Time Off (PTO) is most often available for use as sick OR vacation time. You are likely not required to give a reason along with your request for time off - you should check on that.

If that's the case, no need to lie. Just request the time as vacation with no other reason provided.

Comment: You may not need to provide a reason for planned time off its another if you take the time off with no notice where the company can adjust.